# Apache Ignite Exception - Failed to initialize cache store (data source is not provided)

Tags: ignite

I am trying to implement persistent store for my ignite cache ,I am using CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory,My cache store factory initialization looks like this

```
@Autowired
DataSorce datasource; 
@Bean  
public CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory<?, ?> cacheJdbcdPojoStorefactory(){
CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory<?, ?> factory = new CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory<>();
factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
return factory;
 }
```

My implementation of the cache looks like this

```
CacheConfiguration pesonConfig = new CacheConfiguration();
pesonConfig.setName("personCache");
cacheJdbcdPojoStorefactory.setTypes(jdbcTypes.toArray(new JdbcType[jdbcTypes.size()]));
Collection<QueryEntity> qryEntities = new ArrayList<>();
qryEntities.add(qryEntity);
pesonConfig.setQueryEntities(qryEntities);
pesonConfig.setCacheStoreFactory((Factory<? extends CacheStore<Integer, Person>>) cacheJdbcdPojoStorefactory);
ROCCache<Integer, Person> personCache= rocCachemanager.createCache(pesonConfig);
personCache.put(1, p1);
personCache.put(2, p2)
```

(I am passing correct query Entities and JdbcTypes , for simplicity i have not shown that code here)
But when i run this code i get the below stack trace

```
Failed to initialize cache store (data source is not provided).
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.startLifecycleAware(IgniteUtils.java:8385)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.createCache(GridCacheProcessor.java:1269)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.prepareCacheStart(GridCacheProcessor.java:1638)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.prepareCachesStart(GridCacheProcessor.java:1563)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.startCaches(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:944)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.init(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:511)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:1297)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to initialize cache store (datasource is not provided). at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.CacheAbstractJdbcStore.start(CacheAbstractJdbcStore.java:297)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.startLifecycleAware(IgniteUtils.java:8381)
... 8 more
```

When i debug i can see that my datasource parameters are correctly set inside cacheJdbcdPojoStorefactory object. Where am i going wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of wiring data source bean and setting it to the factory, you can provide its bean ID and the factory will fetch it from the application context. Here is the example:

```
@Bean  
public CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory<?, ?> cacheJdbcdPojoStorefactory(){
    CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory<?, ?> factory = new CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory<>();
    factory.setDataSourceBean("data-source-bean");
    return factory;
}
```

The issue is that factory will be serialized, but data source field is transient. This makes `setDataSource()` property very confusing, I think it should be deprecated and reworked.